# converting objects of buffer to an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, buffer, ejs

how do i convert this buffer data to an image so when am looping thru the result and rendering it in the img src it will render as an image that the user can see

am using ejs to render it

```
     <span>
        <img class="user-with-avatar" src=<%=item.photo%> />
     </span>
```

when i console.log(result.data.photo), i get this

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[100,97,116,97,58,14,79,8,113,97,65,43,57,55,89,69,88,51,66,101,70,86,112,121,112,121,121,121,80,81,104]},
{"type":"Buffer","data":[100,97,116,97,58,14,79,8,113,97,65,43,57,55,89,69,88,51,66,101,70,86,112,121,112,121,121,121,80,81,104]},
{"type":"Buffer","data":[100,97,116,97,58,14,79,8,113,97,65,43,57,55,89,69,88,51,66,101,70,86,112,121,112,121,121,121,80,81,104]}
```

how do i fix it with this code arrangement

```
    app.get('/products', function (req, res) {
            if (req.session.token && req.session.user_id) {
                let data = {
                    token: req.session.token,
                    id: req.session.user_id,
                }
                let url = `https:/url/product/get_products?id=${data.id}&token=${data.token}`
                functions.callAPIGet(
                    url,
                    function (error, result) {
                        res.render('products', {
                            result: result.data
                        })
                    }
                );
            } else {
                res.redirect('/login')
            }
        });
```

Comment: its not working, this just sets the image address to  `data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

encode the buffer in base64:

```js
let base64img = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + result.data.photo.toString('base64');
```

and use base64img in ejs

Comment: its not working, this just sets the image address to `data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object]`

Comment: do you know what those 3 buffers are? try result.data.photo[0].toString('base64')